# Android C2DM Completed project

Tags: android

I am developing an Android project where I have to use C2DM. I need a C2DM sample project or Source code.Please any one help me to give completed project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in this article:

https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/

if you didn't yet use C2DM class in your project I suggest you to look at the new system provided by Google.

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html

And this is a quick example project:

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/demo.html

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html) tutorial
Notice C2DM will no longer be supported as it is deprecated. Move to [GCM](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html)